# How to exclude a folder on Drupal site so that Drupal does not recognise it its own?

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, drupal-6

I am running a site `xyz.org` in Drupal.

Now I want to install some other modules such as **PHPBB** forum and **Coppermine** gallery. When I install these, and try to access the link xyz.org/gallery, it gives me drupal error.

> "Page not found"

What settings I need to change in order to let drupal know that `/gallery` is not a drupal node?

Comment: Ruchir you should mark the answer as accepted with the tick to show it helped.

Answer (score 15):

Take a look at your current .htaccess config. If might have the following lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Those contain most of the URL rewriting that matters. The first three conditions say that all URLs will be rewritten except for existing files, directories and a request for /favicon.ico
You can add your own favourite conditions there. For example, to avoid rewriting for urls of the form /gallery/.*:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/gallery/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, this simple one liner saved me a lot of grief!

Comment: For drupal 7, try:  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/directory_name/.*

Comment: For more details on how to do it on Drupal 7 see: https://www.drupal.org/node/47092#comment-7309216